# Why is shift command not working in concatenation in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, shift

[image]I am posting all the code here.

I get warnings in concatenation in the always block which I don't get:

*concatenation with unsized literal; will interpret as 32 bits*

```
module DECSTAGE(
    input [31:0] Instr, ALU_out,MEM_out,
     input RF_WrEn,RF_WrData_sel,RF_B_sel,
     input Clk,
     output reg [31:0]Immed,
     output [31:0] RF_A,RF_B
    ); 
     
    wire [5:0]Opcode,func;
    wire [4:0]rs,rd,rt;
    wire [15:0]Immediate ;
    /*
        Decoding instruction in:
        - Opcode
        - rs,rd,rt
        - func
        - Immediate
    */
    assign Opcode[5:0] = Instr[31:26];
    assign rs[4:0] = Instr[25:21];
    assign rd[4:0] = Instr[20:16];
    assign rt[4:0] = Instr[15:11];
    assign func[5:0] = Instr[5:0];
    assign Immediate[15:0] = Instr[15:0];
    
    // Needed variables for always block
    reg [4:0]adr2;
    reg [31:0]din;
    // Creating the Register File with 32 registers
    Register_File_RF rgf_RF (.Adr1(rs),.Adr2(adr2),.Awr(rd),.Dout1(RF_A),.Dout2(RF_B),.Din(din),.WrEn(RF_WrEn),.Clk(Clk));
    
    
    always @(posedge Clk)begin
        
        // MUX for rd/rt
        if (RF_B_sel)begin
            adr2 = rd;
        end else begin
            adr2 = rt;
        end
        
        // MUX for ALU_out/MEM_out
        if (RF_WrData_sel)begin
            din = ALU_out;
        end else begin
            din = MEM_out;
        end
        
        // Selecting the Operation for the Immediate
        // SignExtend(Immediate)
        if (Opcode == 6'b111000 || Opcode == 6'b110000 || Opcode ==6'b000111 || 6'b001111 || 6'b011111)begin
            Immed = {{16{Immediate[15]}}, Immediate[15:0]};
        // Immediate << 16 (zeroFill)
        end else if (Opcode == 6'b111001)begin
        
            Immed = {{Immediate[15:0]},{16{0}}};
        
        // ZeroFill(Immediate) 
        end else if (Opcode == 6'b110010 || Opcode == 6'b110011)begin
            Immed = {{16{0}},Immediate[15:0]};
        
        // SignExtend(Immediate)<<2
        end else if (Opcode ==6'b111111 || Opcode == 6'b000000 || Opcode == 6'b000001)begin
            Immed = {{16{Immediate[15]}},Immediate[15:0]}<<2;
        
        // ZeroFill(Immediate) (7 downto 0)
        end else if (Opcode == 6'b000011)begin
            Immed = {{16'b000000000000000000000000},Immediate[7:0]};
        end
    end
    
endmodule
```

According to my simulations, **Immed** is a 32bit, takes the sign of **Immediate[15]** in all 16 bits, takes the Immediate[15:0] in the remaining bits but it never does the shift command.

Here's my simulation:

```
initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    Instr = 0;
    ALU_out = 0;
    MEM_out = 0;
    RF_WrEn = 0;
    RF_WrData_sel = 0;
    RF_B_sel = 0;
    Clk = 0;

    #20;
    Instr = 32'b11111100000000000000000000000011;
    RF_B_sel = 1;
    
    // Add stimulus here

end
```

Comment: The code is updated. The main idea is that you take an Instruction (Instr is input), and you "cut it into pieces". I care about Opcode, which is the first 6 bits of instruction.

Comment: The warnings you are getting for `{16{0}}`should actually be errors. Numeric literals without an explicit size are implicitly 32-bits, and Verilog does not allow you to use implicit numerical literals inside a concatenation. What you should have written  is `{16{1'b0}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never execute the line with the shift because the `if` condition is always true.  The following line is always true because you mistakenly omitted `Opcode ==`  for the last 2 comparisons:

```
    if (Opcode == 6'b111000 || Opcode == 6'b110000 || Opcode ==6'b000111 || 6'b001111 || 6'b011111)begin
```

Change the line to:

```
    if (Opcode == 6'b111000 || Opcode == 6'b110000 || Opcode ==6'b000111 ||  Opcode ==6'b001111 ||  Opcode ==6'b011111)begin
```

---

You get warnings because the replicated concatenation syntax is illegal.  You need to use a sized literal instead of `0`.   You need to change:

```
{16{0}}
```

to:

```
{16{1'b0}}
```